# Reading Inputs using C

Tags: c

I am developing a simple compiler in the cygwin environment using flex and bison generating C code as output and I have generated a sequence of code intended to read two integers followed by a char.

Whereas I thought I knew basic c code I am suffering a problem with the code below where I input two integers, but it never asks for the character after reading the integers!

What is the best way to handle generating code like this, should I always clear the character buffer before performing a scan or a getchar() or have i just made a mistake somewhere!!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

   int a = 0;
   int b = 0;
   char f = '\0';

   scanf("%d",&a);

   scanf("%d",&b);

   f = getchar();
   fflush( stdin );

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Comment: Without compiling this I would guess that the last press of _enter_ on the keyboard is consumed by `getchar()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read each part of the input on a new line, change your `scanf` format string so that it consumes the `'\n'`, since at the moment `f = '\n'`. ie. use `"%d\n"` instead of `"%d"`.

And then you can print the values to make sure (`printf("a: %d, b: %d, f: %c\n", a, b, f);`)

```
$ ./test
2
4
b
a: 2, b: 4, f: b
```

An alternative is also to replace the two `scanf` statements and the `getchar` with a single `scanf` statement: `scanf("%d\n%d\n%c", &a, &b, &f);`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not consuming the newlines left in the input buffers. The changes are the following:

```
scanf("%d\n",&a);

scanf("%d\n",&b);

f = getchar();
```

Comment: Sorry the other guy answered first.